# How can I find out what type of headphones are plugged?

Tags: c++, objective-c, core-audio

I have question about core audio system. Is there any way how to find out what type of headphones are plugged? Or get some information about that. How does iPod app detect it? Core audio is C type things, so is it any way how to do it in C? Any ideas? Thank you for replies.

Comment: Thank you for -1 without reason. I love people like you.

Comment: what sort of type do you mean? If the audio output is via a dock connector or the headphone socket?

Comment: Thank you for help. I want to know information about headphone socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/hondasports/HeadphoneDetector) open source class to determine if headphones are plugged and handle headphones plug or unplugging and audio route changes.

You cannot get programmatically the type of headphones plugged. iPod app detects if you hear from the speaker or from headphones, not the type of the headphones.

Comment: Then how iPod app detects when I have plugged in low quality headphones that can squeeze in high volume and with high quality headphones squeeze in middle volume? Some detections is neccessary I think.

Comment: iPod app is Apple's app. Using public APIs there is no way to make such a detection.